# Singling out lower-dimensional components

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $V\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be defined by equations of degree $\leq D$. (That is, $V$ is an intersection of hypersurfaces of degree $\leq D$.) Assume $V$ is not pure-dimensional. Let $V^-$ be the union of components of $V$ of less than top dimension; denote their maximal dimension by $d^-$. Can we define a variety $W\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ by means of equations of degree $\leq D$ (or $\ll D$) in such a way that (a) $W\cap V$ contains $V^-$, (b) the top dimension of $W\cap V$ is $d^-$?